# Unable to connect AWS EC2 instance via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

It was working fine, I installed Jenkins on EC2 instance. After that, it is working fine in browser but unable to access EC2 instance via SSH? Any lead, what's going wrong or should I need to make any changes to config file. I am running my jenkins instance on port 9090.

Comment: Did you check your ec2's security groups? You should add your port in inbound section of the security group which assigned to your ec2 instance.

Comment: I have already added, maybe Jenkins hogging open shh connections, couldn't identify yet

Comment: Installing Jenkins is probably not the reason why your EC2 is no longer accessible. Did you limit the SSH access to your own IP? Did your IP change meanwhile?

Comment: No I have not implemented any limit, it was working fine before that, After jenkins unable to access through SSH